# Get time difference in minutes in rails the most effective way

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails App, I have a table called Schedule with field called arrival where i entered time and i guess for some reason it got stored in UTC by default in following format

`2000-01-01 07:37:00 UTC`

In my controller when I do something like Time.now I will get a time as such

```
2015-04-26 23:35:46 -0400
```

My problem is need to get both times in same zone or something so i can calculate the difference.

I know i can add 4 hours on my Time.now and make it utc but still how do i get difference between them in minutes? I thought of a stupid hack where if i add 4 hours to Time.now it will become utc and then subtracting difference between both. However time stored in db has 2001 date and this one has 2015 date so will it work? i would suggest your answers or approaches. Thanks

Comment: "for some reason it got stored in UTC" is standard behavior in Rails. Time and DateTime are always converted to and stored as UTC in the database.

Comment: how come it will store the date 2000 ? That i do not understand

Comment: Yeah, the wrong year is definitely not standard behavior. Are you looking directly into the database with MySQL Workbench or are you examining dates through your app? If so, are you sure you're not manipulating the date before storing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem, Ruby handles timezones internally.

```
time1 = DateTime.parse('2000-01-01 10:00:00 UTC')
time2 = DateTime.parse('2000-01-01 10:00:00 -0100')
time2 - time1
# => (1/24)
```

I.e. Ruby already knows that the difference between the same time in UTC and in -0100 is one hour. The time difference operator is already doing the right thing, if you let it :)

However, `DateTime` is Ruby, `Time` is C - the former has a lot nicer API and works awesomely with databases, but the latter is faster.

EDIT: Here's an example using `Time`, still same:

```
time1 = Time.new(2000, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0, "+00:00")
time2 = Time.new(2000, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0, "-01:00")
time2 - time1
# => 3600.0
```

EDIT: Year <strike>2999</strike> 2000

Comment: In my case one has a date 2015 and other has date 2000 so if i do DateTime.parse for both cases and take difference i should get my result in minutes? Thanks so much for this awesome explanation

Comment: No, `DateTime#-` gives you days as a `Rational`. `Time#-` will give you seconds as a `Float`.